# tail /dev/stderr from errors within supervisord php cli script

Tags: linux, php, logging, supervisord, stderr

To make this simple, I want to know if it's possible to access the STDERR like a channel. I don't want the data to log to a file and then tail the file because the amount of information that I want to send in would fill the system. I only care about the data when I want to tap in to what would be sent to STDERR.

I thought that it was possible to tail /dev/stderr in some way, but that doesn't work. The reason I can't use STDOUT is that the script is running in supervisor and anything sent to STDOUT is logged into the program.log file in supervisor. And I'm already outputting some information for that.

Any ideas or thoughts on how to accomplish this would be REALLY helpful!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure supervisord to forward the stdout/stderr of processes it manages to its own stdout/stderr (instead of log files):

http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/08/supervisord-redirecting-stdout.html